# How to power 12V fan and 3V LED with a 9V battery?

Tags: led, fan

I am trying to power a 12V fan and a 3V LED with a 9V battery, but I do not know where to begin. I want the light to automatically be lit up when the 9V battery is connected to clip but the fan will only run when a switch is activated. I have a 330 ohm resistor for the light, but that will cut down the the power for the fan and I was wondering how could I accomplish such a task?

Comment: are you sure your 12V fan can reliably turn on at 9V? even after a little wear? cause if not you need either a lower voltage fan, a boost converter or 2x9V batteries

Comment: Yes, I've tested it with the switch and it runs fine on a 9V, was just trying to get an indicator LED

Comment: How much current does the fan require?  It probably exceeds the capability of a 9V battery unless you only need it to run for a short time. In any case, you will need some sort of boost converter to generate 12V from the battery.

Comment: It runs perfectly with the 9V battery

Comment: 12 Volts and 19mA

Comment: 19mA? Are you sure? That sounds like it's not very much.

Comment: Yes, I am certain, that's what it says on the fan

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your fan will reliably turn on as you state, and assuming your battery can supply enough current for the LED and Fan, this will provide the functionality that you need.

1 - When battery is connected, LED lights up.

2 - When battery is connected and switch is turned on, FAN will turn on.

The 330R resistor you said you have should give about 20mA for most LEDs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkRZSw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the schematic! I tried this, but the fan is not powered, only the LED

Comment: I guess my battery isn't supplying enough

Comment: If it works separately with the LED+resistor and Fan, but not with both thats most likely the case. Do you have a multimeter to measure how much current your battery is capable of supplying?

Comment: Some small 12 volt fans can consume 1/8th to 1/4 amps of current, much more than a 9 volt battery can sustain. 9 volt batteries are designed for < 1mA of current drain, or less. They are for long term use such as smoke alarms, etc.

Comment: have you tried using 6x AA batteries ? instead of a single 9V battery.

Comment: some of them should last at least a couple hours at 50~100mA.. problem might be that the fan wont turn on at 5~6V anymore.. http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/522.pdf (p.s.: they should and they do, I've used tens of them in single event applications)

Comment: although yes, I agree thats not ideal

Comment: Hey , i added a 3V pack to the circuit and dropped the resistor and it's all working. thanks for your answer as i wouldn't have the idea where to start without it! :)

Comment: the resistor is protecting the LED from overcurrents though, if eventually you add a battery with higher current capacity you will want to put the resistor back

Comment: Yeah, I added the resistor again lol... thank you for all the help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Wire the led and resistor directly to the battery connector wires. That's your indicator.

Now wire a switch and the fan in parallel. You are done.

Comment: I appreciate it!